# Spec Date Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, rspec

I want to add a birthday date to my user model, this is how I implemented it:

**user.rb**

```
validates_date :birthday_date
```

**user_spec.rb**

```
describe User do

before(:each) do
@attr = {
  :birthday_date =>  Date.new(1992, 8, 27),
  :nom => "Utilisateur",
  :email => "user@example.com",
  :password => "foobar",
  :password_confirmation => "foobar"
}
end

it "..." do
 User.create!(@attr)
end

it "must have a correct date" do
  bad_guy = User.new(@attr.merge(:birthday_date => ""))
  bad_guy.should_not be_valid
end
```

But when I want to test it, I have got this error :

```
Failure/Error: @follower = Factory(:user)
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Birthday date is not a valid date
```

Why is my date not accepted?

Comment: Can you update your question with the details of Factory `user`. Also, where have you defined `@follower = Factory(:user)` in spec file. Share that.

Comment: I forget to update my factory file. I just had   user.date_de_naissance      Date.new(1992,05,27) and now it's work ! Thank you